# Unable to invoke procedure in IBM worklight

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I'm using worklight to dev an app for wp8. I have a trouble when using SQLAdapter.

In my SQLAdapter.xml file :

```
<procedure name="checkUser"/>
```

When I deploy and invoke it, it run well.

But when I invoke it from my js file.

```
function checkUser(username){

var invoData = {
        adapter : 'SQLAdapter',
        procedure : 'checkUser',
        parameters : [username]
    };
alert("OK1");
WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invoData,{
    onSuccess : checkUserSuccess,
    onFailure : checkUserFailure
});
alert("OK2");
```

}

```
function checkUserSuccess(result){
alert("check Success");
WL.Logger.debug("load data success");
var invocationResult = result.invocationResult;
var isSuccessful = invocationResult.isSuccessful;
if (true == isSuccessful) {
    var result = invocationResult.resultSet;
    alert(result.length);
}else{
    alert("Try again later...");
}
```

}

```
function checkUserFailure(result){
alert("Sorry ! No connection found...");
WL.Logger.debug("load data fail");
```

}

It only alert OK1, and not alert OK2, something wrong in WL.Client.invokeProcedure but I dont know how to fix it. Anyone can help me ??

Edit:
I found the reason : I invoke it out from default js file. When I copy to index.js, it run correctly.

Comment: Does your applciation go into the checkUserSuccess or checkUserFailure function as expected? Are any of your other debug statements output. Please provide more info

Comment: It would also be useful to see the execution log from the device (or WP8 emulator) from when this is run.  Can you share that with us?

Answer (score 0):

you could try to set a timeout like that :

```
 WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invoData,{
     onSuccess : checkUserSuccess,
     onFailure : checkUserFailure,
     timeout:30000 });
```

regards,